# How to track amount of inputs that have been inputted by a user? C Program

Tags: c, tracking

EDIT: I am so sorry for the inconvenience but I had to take out the original code that I had used to submit this question. I will reupload my old code and the new code later! But the answer that is still up was very helpful in understanding how to track the number of inputs that are inputted by a user using a do ... while loop.

For this assignment, we were supposed to create a random guessing game where user inputs a number between 1 and 100 and has 3 functions (int getRandomNumber(void), int check4Win(int,int) and void printResults(int)). getRandomNumber was just made to create the random number, check4Win was just to tell the user if their guess is too high, too low, or correct and for printResults we are supposed to rank the user based on how many guesses they inputted. My issue is with printResults and what goes in main to actually keep track of how many guesses the user inputted. I was able to get the entire code to work but my main issue is being able to keep track of the number of inputs because what I have now is printing out the first input rather than the number of inputs. I will include my entire code but the main issue is printResults. The rest of them seem fine but if you think there is an issue somewhere else please let me know! I know that I used a switch statement inside the for statement in main and I am about 99.9% sure that is wrong I just couldn't figure out what else to do. Also, the formatting is off a bit here but that's just so that the code can stay together its formatted fine on my compiler! I am also fairly new to so I will take all criticism.
Thank you!

Comment: Why is the loop counting up to `guessNum`?

Comment: Hi! That part is the part of the issue I'm having. Honestly, I had something better there but I accidentally deleted it, and I was trying to see if I could do a switch statement because I had seen an example that did a for loop then a switch statement which kept track of the guesses. I didn't know what else to do but that's all I had so I left it!

Comment: Regarding the actual issue, you are calling `printResults(guessNum);` .. of course that is your last "input" because that's the variable you're using to store it.  If you want to count guesses, then store the count somewhere and use _that_ when calling `printResults`.  Right now, you've collapsed the count as a loop variable.  That loop makes no sense.  And your program is barely readable.  Please study how to correctly indent code.

Comment: Hi @paddy! Thank you for your feedback! I did mention that the format here was wrong but on my compiler is fine, I just needed it to format together so it would submit the code altogether. For that loop, that will come out for sure it's just there for now but I originally had printResults(guessAmount) which would be the phrase that tracks the guesses I just don't understand how to do the tracking part if that makes sense.

Comment: When in doubt, explain the entire process, step by step, as clearly as you can, in plain English words in a separate document. Or write it on paper with pen or pencil, if you find that helps. Drawing diagrams (physically, with pen and paper) can also help.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for your advice! That sounds like it would really help, whatever my next assignment is I'll for sure be doing that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of how to count "guesses" until success.  You can extend as you see fit, whether that is to move stuff into functions, add "maximum guesses" logic, use proper input handling (this will break if you input a non-integer, like `hello`).

```
int randNum = getRandomNumber();
int guessNum = 0;
int guessCount = 0;

do {
    printf("Guess #%d: ", guessCount + 1);
    scanf("%d", &guessNum);

    // validate
    if (guessNum < 1 || guessNum > 100)
    {
        printf("Invalid guess\n");
        continue;
    }
    ++guessCount;

    // check
    if (guessNum < randNum)
        printf("Too low\n");
    else if (guessNum > randNum)
        printf("Too high\n");

} while(guessNum != randNum);

printf("Total guesses: %d\n", guessCount);
```

My advice is you manage input in *one* place.  I couldn't stomach the way you're doing input in main, but then the "check4win" function tries to input values too.  A function should do what its name implies.  That function "checks" something, so one would expect that it returns some kind of value that indicates the result of "checking".  That's all it should do.  Since it's called "check4Win", I would expect it returns true if the guess "wins" and false otherwise.

Comment: Haha, I'm sorry about that @paddy! The rules for this assignment are VERY weird so if I had a choice I certainly would not have done it this way at all. I will see if we can do it where there are no inputs in check4Win because it definitely seems better that way but the way my professor explained it seems like it had to also include that but honestly I could have easily misread it. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out and I am going to include the ways you said and I'll update what I got, thank you so much!